# How to call javascript function while loading a new template?

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-framework-beans

I am working with spring framework. My project is a "Maven Project".

```
//This is a function inside my navigator.jsp file
function selectNavigator(id) {
    var color = "";
    var colorSelected = "rgba(80,165,219)";
    $("#nav-beacons").css("background-color", color);
    $("#nav-messages").css("background-color", color);
    $("#nav-locations").css("background-color", color);
    $("#nav-analytics").css("background-color", color);
    $("#nav-company").css("background-color", color);
    $("#nav-users").css("background-color", color);
    $(id).css("background-color", colorSelected);
}
```

This function changes the selected item's background with particular color while leaving the rest of navigation items un-colored.

And this is my template...

```
<definition name="mainTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/templates/dashboard/index.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Home" />
    <put-attribute name="heading" value="Home" />
    <put-attribute name="onLoad" value="selectNavigator('nav-users')" />
    <put-attribute name="header"    value="/WEB-INF/templates/dashboard/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body">
        <definition template="/WEB-INF/templates/dashboard/body.jsp">
            <put-attribute name="navigator" value="/WEB-INF/templates/dashboard/navigator.jsp" />
            <put-attribute name="body_content" value="" />
        </definition>
    </put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="footer"    value="/WEB-INF/templates/dashboard/footer.jsp" />  
</definition>
```

I have my "selectNavigator" function be called "onload" but it doesn't work. and I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: the syntax is `onload=myFunction()' I think the whole syntax is incorrect

Comment: it's a type while I was copy pasting it onto the thread. It doesn't work even with `onload=myFunction()'

Comment: did ssostalker's solution worked?

Comment: no _____ @JSmith

Answer (score 0):

I can see a syntax error in this line

```
 <put-attribute name="onLoad" value="selectNavigator("nav-users" />
```

Replace it with

```
 <put-attribute name="onLoad" value="selectNavigator('nav-users')" />
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
<put-attribute onload="selectNavigator('nav-users')" />
```